# Accessing ngModel from within Angular 2 structural directive

Tags: angular

I am writing my own structural directive in Angular 2 that is applied to an input-element like this:

```
<input #name="ngModel" *myFormControl="name" type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="contact.name" name="name">
```

In the directive's constructor I create an embedded view in the view container from the templateRef like this:

```
constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    ...
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(templateRef)
    ...
```

As you see, I am using the template variable #name bound to the input's ngModel as input for my structural directive. However, when the setter of myFormControl is invoked

```
@Input()
set myFormControl( model ) {
    this._model = mode;
}
```

the value of 'model' is undefined.

Any ideas how I could get a handle of the input's ngModel in my structural directive?

Thanks a lot!!!